# how to calculate public key of a certificate in JAVA which match with the public key calculated by windows

Tags: java, certificate

```
In our project we need to calculate the public key of a certificate and sha1 hash of public key. I tried to do this using java API "X509Certificate.getPublicKey()" and then calculated the hexadecimal representation of it. But the value obtained through this process does not match with the value that windows shows for "Public Key" when certificate is opened by double clicking it.
```

As an example, I calculated the public key for following certificate (in PEM format)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICxDCCAi2gAwIBAgIBBjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBujELMAkGA1UEBhMCSU4x
EDAOBgNVBAgMB0hhcnlhbmExEDAOBgNVBAcMB0d1cmdhb24xDzANBgNVBAoMBk1j
QWZlZTEbMBkGA1UECwwSQXBwbGljYXRpb25Db250cm9sMTIwMAYDVQQDDClNY0Fm
ZWVBcHBsaWNhdGlvbkNvbnRyb2xUZXN0Q2VydEF1dGhvcml0eTElMCMGCSqGSIb3
DQEJARYWYXBwX2NvbnRyb2xAbWNhZmVlLmNvbTAeFw0xMjAzMTMxMDM4MDZaFw0x
MzA3MjYxMDM4MDZaMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjEQMA4GA1UECBMHSGFyeWFuYTEQ
MA4GA1UEBxMHR3VyZ2FvbjEUMBIGA1UEChMLdGVzdENvbXBhbnkxEDAOBgNVBAsT
B3Rlc3RPcmcxETAPBgNVBAMTCHRlc3ROYW1lMSYwJAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhd0ZXN0
TmFtZUB0ZXN0RG9tYWluLmNvbTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEA
qjRldfjFgIqMrXiNcKYA31bX+nLsw3Q0CeBiWq3oDh3sz/gk7dz+9yLRub+gnosU
Sgj0td5yolhmCKPq9YZe5q/YLm9vsbU6WJr4VU3Uwi4uHTPZxojjUjx9esqTS1uh
AQJhT1BxOLJ+HNb/VqwZ66SB7mPhK2BTT7Kym5zCApsCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQQFAAOBgQB7yiAwtYiB05lJf+kUCgOmfUx/18ZJPB1Am+fIr+aMo2Djgv7bLPG5
vesq0t1opBJIS9LqswW8Bf3IGdhc+33+LYRVxUB8mLHZ2KyCqfuuT7PdHHsiyNDg
uMdO+equDFUsTMv0y6KyzCf89ZPjGhS4O09zVyR/KtZzSE6dyvyBNg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The hexadecimal representation of public key calculated by java API is
    30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d0030818902818100aa346575f8c5808a8cad788d70a600df56d7fa72ecc3743409e0625aade80e1deccff824eddcfef722d1b9bfa09e8b144a08f4b5de72a2586608a3eaf5865ee6afd82e6f6fb1b53a589af8554dd4c22e2e1d33d9c688e3523c7d7aca934b5ba10102614f507138b27e1cd6ff56ac19eba481ee63e12b60534fb2b29b9cc2029b0203010001

on the other hand the hexadecimal representation of public key as showed by window (when we double click a certificate the value of Public Key is present in details tab) is following
    30818902818100aa346575f8c5808a8cad788d70a600df56d7fa72ecc3743409e0625aade80e1deccff824eddcfef722d1b9bfa09e8b144a08f4b5de72a2586608a3eaf5865ee6afd82e6f6fb1b53a589af8554dd4c22e2e1d33d9c688e3523c7d7aca934b5ba10102614f507138b27e1cd6ff56ac19eba481ee63e12b60534fb2b29b9cc2029b0203010001

So, the public key calculated by java API and by windows are different. What I have observed is that the public key showed by window is same as the value from 45th character in java API calculated public key.

So, please help us understand how window calculates the public key of a certificate so, that we can use the same mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below post for the detailed answer.

This is because of the additional meta-data that windows strips and is available in java.

[how to convert public key of an x509 certificate in JAVA to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767309/how-to-convert-public-key-of-an-x509-certificate-in-java-to-hex)