# X509 Public Key to HEX

Tags: java, cryptography, hex, x509certificate, public-key

I have a `PublicKey` (`java.security.PublicKey`). 
I need to convert it into HEX string.

Like when you open certificate (on Windows for ex.) and look at Public Key information. You will see:

`04 40 ad 77 10 45 08 f2 3a ae 1d 1d 95 22 2f b3 f5 e5 2f da db 8c 39 3a 03 15 fb 4b 36 28 46 de 7b 00 f4 73 11 ae b9 ac 00 aa 19 34 6d fb 7c 56 b1 93 c0 1b 86 7c d0 a2 0b 4d 22 a9 d2 4d b0 f6 34 c4` (*)

Any ideas how to do that?

EDIT:

I tried:

```
Hex.encodeHexString(cert.getPublicKey.getEncoded)
```

It returns me a string:

```
3063301c06062a8503020213301206072a85030202230106072a850302021e01034300_0440ad77104508f23aae1d1d95222fb3f5e52fdadb8c393a0315fb4b362846de7b00f47311aeb9ac00aa19346dfb7c56b193c01b867cd0a20b4d22a9d24db0f634c4
```

This string contains HEX value (*) (i placed _ where it starts).

Comment: Well have you tried *anything* yet? `PublicKey` has a `getEncoded()` method to return the bytes, and then you just need a byte array to hex conversion - which there are many examples of on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I tried. `getEncoded` returns the key in its primary encoding format. In my case it's X.509. Well, how to decode it?

Comment: What makes you think you need to decode it? If you convert the bytes returned by `getEncoded()` into hex, how does that compare with the hex you've shown in the question?

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the question. Looks like getting a Hex from key bytes contains needed value + something. I thought I have to decode it because: 1. method name: getEncoded. 2. comments for `java.security.Key.getEncoded` "Returns the key in its primary encoding format, or null if this key does not support encoding"

Comment: What do you want to do with this public key? Is this an RSA key? What parts of it do you need: modulus (`n`) or public exponent (`e`) or both? In what format? (I don't know what format _Windows for ex._ uses.)

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767309/how-to-convert-public-key-of-an-x509-certificate-in-java-to-hex

Comment: What library are you using for your GOST functionality in Java? I'm typing an answer, but I need to know if I want to show you the easy way of getting the public key value (the hard way is to parse the key you get from `getEncoded()`).

Comment: @Roman That's about an RSA key, this is something [pretty different](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#3063301C06062A8503020213301206072A85030202230106072A850302021E010343000440AD77104508F23AAE1D1D95222FB3F5E52FDADB8C393A0315FB4B362846DE7B00F47311AEB9AC00AA19346DFB7C56B193C01B867CD0A20B4D22A9D24DB0F634C4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in Java is called `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`, which is indeed specified in the Java. You can view it online [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#3063301C06062A8503020213301206072A85030202230106072A850302021E010343000440AD77104508F23AAE1D1D95222FB3F5E52FDADB8C393A0315FB4B362846DE7B00F47311AEB9AC00AA19346DFB7C56B193C01B867CD0A20B4D22A9D24DB0F634C4). As we can see it is a Russian GOST Elliptic Curve public key. It contains the OID's (object identifiers) of the public key format, the Elliptic Curve domain parameters and the hash identifier.

As you can also see the value you get from Microsoft is a bit odd. The actual public key value is:

```
ad77104508f23aae1d1d95222fb3f5e52fdadb8c393a0315fb4b362846de7b00f47311aeb9ac00aa19346dfb7c56b193c01b867cd0a20b4d22a9d24db0f634c4
```

The `0440` just indicates that this value is encoded as an octet string (aka byte array). Even more precisely it's the point:

```
(78460489894733727260622807718072211860518873236604684346084533999519831849728, 110567644507038660207162091352707227223755109412227308137485312229644099269828)
```

on the 256 bit curve. You get these values by splitting the binary string precisely through the middel (either coordinate has the same size as the curve due to the way they are encoded).

Now if you want to get the public key value you can go (at least) two ways about it. Either you parse the bytes you get back from `getEncoded` or you find out the actual type of your `PublicKey`, cast it to that type, and then use the additional functionality of the specific class to retrieve information about the public key, such as the Elliptic Curve point.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cast public key to GostPublicKey, then called `getDecoded.asInstanceOf[SubjectPublicKeyInfo]` (from `ru.CryptoPro.JCP.ASN.PKIX1Explicit88.SubjectPublicKeyInfo` package). And its possible to get subjectPublicKey from SubjectPublicKeyInfo, it returns me Asn1BitString.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below to get public key value in a representation same as windows.

```
PublicKey publicKey = ...;
String publickKeyHexValue = Hex.toHexString(publicKey.getEncoded());
```

ps: I used `BouncyCastle` Library and in particular `HEX` class in `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders` package.